# Guice Dependency Injection in dropwizard not working - is it a pom.xml artifacts dependency problem?

Tags: java, rest, dependency-injection, dropwizard, dropwizard-guice

I want to run a Dropwizard  (a REST Application).

I have a pom.xml file that uses old version of dropwizard (1.0.3) and it works.
And there is another pom.xml available bellow for the new version (2.0.10) but it does not run.

Here is the working pom.xml (1.0.3 version of DropWizard) which is available on githut :

https://github.com/userInterview/dropwizard-guice

Just copy past the pom.xml to reproduce the error or the working version.

**Here are the two pom.xml files :**

- Here is the corresponding pom.xml for old DropWizard Release (1.03 ) that works

  ```
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <prerequisites>
       <maven>3.0.0</maven>
   </prerequisites>

   <groupId>ca.rasul</groupId>
   <artifactId>dwguice</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>

   <name>DWGuice</name>

   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
       <dropwizard.version>1.0.3</dropwizard.version>
       <hubspot.guice.version>1.0.0.1</hubspot.guice.version>
       <google.guice.version>4.1</google.guice.version>
       <mainClass>ca.rasul.DWGuiceApplication</mainClass>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
           <artifactId>dropwizard-bom</artifactId>
           <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
           <type>pom</type>
           <scope>import</scope>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
           <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
           <version>4.1.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <!--hubspot's integration of guice-->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.hubspot.dropwizard</groupId>
           <artifactId>dropwizard-guice</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.0</version>
       </dependency>


   </dependencies>

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.4.1</version>
               <configuration>
                   <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                   <transformers>
                       <transformer
                               implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                       <transformer
                               implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                           <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                       </transformer>
                   </transformers>
                   <!-- exclude signed Manifests -->
                   <filters>
                       <filter>
                           <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                           <excludes>
                               <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                               <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                               <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                           </excludes>
                       </filter>
                   </filters>
               </configuration>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <phase>package</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>shade</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.6</version>
               <configuration>
                   <archive>
                       <manifest>
                           <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                           <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                       </manifest>
                   </archive>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.3</version>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.8</source>
                   <target>1.8</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.4</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>attach-sources</id>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>jar</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.10.3</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>jar</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.4</version>
               <configuration>
                   <reportPlugins>
                       <plugin>
                           <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>2.4</version>
                           <configuration>
                               <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                               <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                           </configuration>
                       </plugin>
                       <plugin>
                           <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>2.10.3</version>
                       </plugin>
                   </reportPlugins>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
  ```
- Here is the corresponding pom.xml for new DropWizard release (2.0.10)
  that does not work :

  ```
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <prerequisites>
       <maven>3.0.0</maven>
   </prerequisites>

   <groupId>ca.rasul</groupId>
   <artifactId>dwguice</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>

   <name>DWGuice</name>

   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
       <dropwizard.version>2.0.10</dropwizard.version>
       <hubspot.guice.version>1.0.0.1</hubspot.guice.version>
       <google.guice.version>4.1</google.guice.version>
       <mainClass>ca.rasul.DWGuiceApplication</mainClass>
   </properties>

   <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
               <artifactId>dropwizard-dependencies</artifactId>
               <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
               <type>pom</type>
               <scope>import</scope>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

   <dependencies>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
           <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
           <artifactId>dropwizard-jdbi</artifactId>
           <version>2.0.0-rc9</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.hubspot.dropwizard</groupId>
           <artifactId>dropwizard-guice</artifactId>
           <version>1.3.5.0</version>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
                   <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
           <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
           <version>4.2.3</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.4.1</version>
               <configuration>
                   <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                   <transformers>
                       <transformer
                           implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                       <transformer
                           implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                           <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                       </transformer>
                   </transformers>
                   <!-- exclude signed Manifests -->
                   <filters>
                       <filter>
                           <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                           <excludes>
                               <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                               <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                               <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                           </excludes>
                       </filter>
                   </filters>
               </configuration>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <phase>package</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>shade</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.6</version>
               <configuration>
                   <archive>
                       <manifest>
                           <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                           <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                       </manifest>
                   </archive>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.3</version>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.8</source>
                   <target>1.8</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.4</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>attach-sources</id>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>jar</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.10.3</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>jar</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.4</version>
               <configuration>
                   <reportPlugins>
                       <plugin>
                           <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>2.4</version>
                           <configuration>
                               <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                               <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                           </configuration>
                       </plugin>
                       <plugin>
                           <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>2.10.3</version>
                       </plugin>
                   </reportPlugins>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
  ```

I have that application available on github if someone wants to bring som help here :)

https://github.com/userInterview/dropwizard-guice

When i run the application i have the following error on console :

```
loizani@DevBoxHouse:~/git/dropwizard-guice-sample$ java -jar target/dwguice-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server config-dev.yml
WARN  [2021-02-17 23:39:04,518] com.squarespace.jersey2.guice.JerseyGuiceUtils: It appears jersey2-guice-spi is either not present or in conflict with some other Jar: ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl(hk2-locator, 229995302)
INFO  [2021-02-17 22:39:05,636] io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory: Registering jersey handler with root path prefix: /
INFO  [2021-02-17 22:39:05,645] io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory: Registering admin handler with root path prefix: /
INFO  [2021-02-17 22:39:05,649] io.dropwizard.server.ServerFactory: Starting DWGuice
================================================================================

                              DWGuice

================================================================================

INFO  [2021-02-17 22:39:05,882] org.eclipse.jetty.setuid.SetUIDListener: Opened application@2516fc68{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
INFO  [2021-02-17 22:39:05,899] org.eclipse.jetty.setuid.SetUIDListener: Opened admin@304a9d7b{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8081}
INFO  [2021-02-17 22:39:05,901] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: jetty-9.4.29.v20200521; built: 2020-05-21T17:20:40.598Z; git: 77c232aed8a45c818fd27232278d9f95a021095e; jvm 1.8.0_201-b09
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessagingBinders$HeaderDelegateProviders does not implement the requested interface org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.Binder
        at com.squarespace.jersey2.guice.JerseyGuiceUtils.bind(JerseyGuiceUtils.java:337)
        at com.squarespace.jersey2.guice.JerseyGuiceUtils.link(JerseyGuiceUtils.java:321)
        at com.squarespace.jersey2.guice.JerseyGuiceUtils.link(JerseyGuiceUtils.java:287)
        at com.squarespace.jersey2.guice.JerseyGuiceModule$ServiceLocatorProvider.get(JerseyGuiceModule.java:111)
        at com.squarespace.jersey2.guice.JerseyGuiceModule$ServiceLocatorProvider.get(JerseyGuiceModule.java:96)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:59)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:168)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:213)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:184)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:111)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createChildInjector(InjectorImpl.java:246)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createChildInjector(InjectorImpl.java:251)
        at com.hubspot.dropwizard.guice.GuiceBundle$1.create(GuiceBundle.java:121)
        at com.squarespace.jersey2.guice.GuiceServiceLocatorGenerator.create(GuiceServiceLocatorGenerator.java:70)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.internalCreate(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:289)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.create(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:245)
        at com.squarespace.jersey2.guice.GuiceServiceLocatorFactory.create(GuiceServiceLocatorFactory.java:88)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.createLocator(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.<init>(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:62)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.<init>(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:38)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory$Hk2InjectionManagerStrategy$1.createInjectionManager(Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.java:55)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.create(Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.java:73)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createInjectionManager(Injections.java:69)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:259)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:347)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:602)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:413)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:749)
        at java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:352)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
        at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:773)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:360)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:844)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:275)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.doStart(InstrumentedHandler.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:425)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.doStart(StatisticsHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:408)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand.run(ServerCommand.java:53)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:45)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:87)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
        at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:94)
        at ca.rasul.DWGuiceApplication.main(DWGuiceApplication.java:15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the server starts normally if i use another kind of artifact, which is a modern one : "dropwizard-guicey" in version 5.2.0

Remark : the enpoint "/brands/name" does not work ! It is because of an  Injection problem. (beware !)

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <mainclass>com.dropwizard.application.MainApplication</mainclass>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.vyarus</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-guicey</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```